# How to Read file and store content into a 2D matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matrix

I have a ton of data file in the same format as described below and I'm trying to make a colormesh plot from this:

```
0 0 1 2 
-3 1 7 7 
-2 1 2 3 
-1 1 7 3
```

`[0 1 2]` of the first row are values for the y axis of the plot, and `[-3 -2 -1]` of the first column are values for the x values of the same plot. The first `0` is only for spacing

these are the numbers that I really want inside the pcolormesh:

```
1 7 7
1 2 3
1 7 3
```

I'm trying to read these values and store into a 2D matrix as:

```
Matrix = [[1.  7.  7.]
          [1.  2.  3.]
          [1.  7.  3.]]
```

Here is a figure ilustrating it further:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# ------------- Input Data Files ------------- # 

data = np.loadtxt('my_colormesh_data.dat')  # Load Data File

# ------ Transform Data into 2D Matrix ------- # 
Matrix = []

n_row = 4                                   # Number of rows counting 0 from file   #
n_column = 4                                # Number of columns couting 0 from file # 

x = data[range(1,n_row),0]                  # Read x axis values from data file and store in a variable #  
y = data[0, range(1,n_column)]              # Read y axis values from data file and store in a variable #
print(data)

print('\n', x)                              # print values of x (for checking)
print('\n', y)                              # print values of y (for checking)


for i in range (2, n_row):
    for j in range(2, n_column):
        print(i, j, data[i,j])              # print values of i, j and data (for checking)
        Matrix[i,j] = data[i,j]

print(Matrix)
```

and results in this error:

```
Matrix[i,j] = data[i,j]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Could you clarify what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting the error because `Matrix` is a list and you are trying to index it using a `tuple`, `i,j`. And that is not a valid operation. You can index a list oly with `integers` or `slices`

Secondly your `data` variable is already a `2D` array. You don't have to any further conversions.

In order to skip the first row and first column you can simply use index slicing.

```py
>>> input_data = """0 0 1 2
... -3 1 7 7
... -2 1 2 3
... -1 1 7 3 """
>>>
>>> data = np.loadtxt(StringIO(input_data))
>>> data
array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  2.],
       [-3.,  1.,  7.,  7.],
       [-2.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [-1.,  1.,  7.,  3.]])
```

---

```
>>> data[1:,1:]
array([[1., 7., 7.],
       [1., 2., 3.],
       [1., 7., 3.]])
```